# Why does pacman/packer always fail 3 times to connect, and makes it the fourth?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management

I think this will explain better:

```
:: Retrieving packages ...
error: failed retrieving file 'gpm-1.20.7-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.us.leaseweb.net : Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds
error: failed retrieving file 'gpm-1.20.7-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.de.leaseweb.net : Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds
error: failed retrieving file 'gpm-1.20.7-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.nl.leaseweb.net : Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds
 gpm-1.20.7-2-x86_64                                                              131.8 KiB  65.1K/s 00:02 [###############################################################] 100%
error: failed retrieving file 'vim-runtime-7.3.875-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.us.leaseweb.net : Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds
error: failed retrieving file 'vim-runtime-7.3.875-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.de.leaseweb.net : Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds
error: failed retrieving file 'vim-runtime-7.3.875-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.nl.leaseweb.net : Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds
 vim-runtime-7.3.875-1-x86_64                                                       4.4 MiB  67.1K/s 01:07 [###############################################################] 100%
error: failed retrieving file 'ruby-2.0.0_p0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.us.leaseweb.net : Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds
error: failed retrieving file 'ruby-2.0.0_p0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.de.leaseweb.net : Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds
error: failed retrieving file 'ruby-2.0.0_p0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.nl.leaseweb.net : Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds
 ruby-2.0.0_p0-1-x86_64                                                             3.4 MiB  57.8K/s 01:00 [###############################################################] 100%
error: failed retrieving file 'lua-5.2.2-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.us.leaseweb.net : Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds
error: failed retrieving file 'lua-5.2.2-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.de.leaseweb.net : Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds
error: failed retrieving file 'lua-5.2.2-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.nl.leaseweb.net : Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds
 lua-5.2.2-1-x86_64                                                               231.2 KiB  69.6K/s 00:03 [###############################################################] 100%
```

This happens with absolutely *every* package. I assure you. It tries to get the file, doesn't work though, it tries again and again, and then it works.

Looking at it closely I'm guessing it's the servers from which it's trying to get the files, correct?

If so, where would I change the order of these servers to an order that works better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently those three servers are timing out; when pacman tries the fourth server, it succeeds. Or you have another problem in your network (I can resolve and connect to them).

Try editing `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist` and changing the servers.